# Java JPA - Inner Join Query doesn't work

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, eclipselink

I'm currently having an issue using Java JPA with EclipseLink - this query:

```js
SELECT  VAR_INPUT.*
FROM VAR_INPUT
INNER JOIN TYPE_VAR_INPUT
ON VAR_INPUT.ID_TYPE_VAR_INPUT = TYPE_VAR_INPUT.ID_TYPE_VAR_INPUT
WHERE TYPE_VAR_INPUT.IS_MANDATORY_TYPE_VAR_INPUT=true;
```

is working fine when run directly on my database, but doesn't work when I use it with JPA.

JPA Query:

```js
@NamedQuery(name = "VarInput.findAVarInputllOfMandatoryType", 
            query = "SELECT v "
                    + "FROM VarInput v "
                    + "INNER JOIN TypeVarInput t "
                    + "ON v.ID_TYPE_VAR_INPUT = t.ID_TYPE_VAR_INPUT "
                    + "WHERE t.isMandatoryTypeVarInput=:isMandatoryTypeVarInput"),
```

When I execute it in my Java application, I get the following error:
"The field [VAR_INPUT.ID_VAR_INPUT] in this expression has an invalid table in this context."

```js
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-6069] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: The field [VAR_INPUT.ID_VAR_INPUT] in this expression has an invalid table in this context.
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="VarInput.findAVarInputllOfMandatoryType" referenceClass=VarInput jpql="SELECT v FROM VarInput v INNER JOIN TypeVarInput t ON v.ID_TYPE_VAR_INPUT = t.ID_TYPE_VAR_INPUT WHERE t.isMandatoryTypeVarInput=:isMandatoryTypeVarInput")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.invalidTableForFieldInExpression(QueryException.java:749)  at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.invalidTableForFieldInExpression(QueryException.java:749)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.FieldExpression.validateNode(FieldExpression.java:296)
```

My tables looks like that:

```html
Table VAR_INPUT(ID_VAR_INPUT, NAME_VAR_INPUT, ID_TYPE_VAR_INPUT)
Table TYPE_VAR_INPUT(ID_TYPE_VAR_INPUT, NAME_TYPE_VAR_INPUT, IS_MANDATORY_VAR_INPUT)
"VAR_INPUT ManyToOne TYPE_VAR_INPUT"
```

Do you have any idea of why this happens?

NB: The Entities were generated by NetBeans

Comment: without the classes it would be impossible to match things up to JPQL ... you don't use table/column names in JPQL

Comment: fixed small grammar/spelling mistakes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use `inner join` in JQPL like that, you join on entity fields. I'm guessing now since you didn't provide entity code, but try this

```
@NamedQuery(name = "VarInput.findAVarInputllOfMandatoryType", 
            query = "SELECT v "
                    + "FROM VarInput v "
                    + "join v.type t "
                    + "WHERE t.isMandatoryTypeVarInput=:isMandatoryTypeVarInput")
```

In this case you don't even need to join, you can simplify the query to this (inner join is implicitly used)

```
@NamedQuery(name = "VarInput.findAVarInputllOfMandatoryType", 
            query = "SELECT v "
                    + "FROM VarInput v "
                    + "WHERE v.type.isMandatoryTypeVarInput=:isMandatoryTypeVarInput")
```